# How does light weight processes works?

Tags: operating-system

How exactly the *light weight process* works, and why do we need to map user threads with kernel threads?

Also, does light weight processes comes in to picture only in OS which supports kernel threads?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Light Weight Processes`(lwp) runs in user space on top of a single kernel thread and shares its address space and system resources with other LWPs within the same process. Multiple user level threads, managed by a thread library, can be placed on top of one or many LWPs - allowing multitasking to be done at the user level.
Now the reason behind that is `LWPs are slower and more expensive` to create than user threads. Whenever an LWP is created a system call must first be made to create a corresponding kernel thread, causing a switch to kernel mode.Hence creating Multiple user level thread in the same space works faster with no system call and pre-emption and providing multitasking.

Comment: Switching of kernel threads may become very expensive as well, so true for LWPs as well due to change in memory mappings.